# Dynamically changing images in the DOM

Tags: javascript, loops, dom

I'm trying to add a health meter representation to a game I'm working on and stuck on a DOM manipulation problem.  The idea is that there is an image that deteriorates in various stages as the player loses health.  Here is an example of what I have so far.

```
var healthDisplay = document.getElementById('healthDisplay');
      if (heroHealth > 75) {
        healthDisplay.src = 'image1.png';
      } else if (heroHealth < 75 || heroHealth > 30){
        healthDisplay.src = 'image2.png';
      } else {
        healthDisplay.src = 'image3.png';
      };
```

That's just the basics of it.  My question is about the next step.  What do I add to make it so the script is constantly checking to see if these parameters are true or false?  Would it be best to put it in a while loop, or add an event listener?

Comment: put it inside of `setInterval`

Comment: It depends on the factors, which are going to change health rate. If you say time, you can use setInterval or if it depends on mouse movement use should use different things like EventListeners according to mouse movements.

Comment: Show how you're updating the health, since that would seem to be where this belongs.

Comment: I would have the change triggered by a custom event. Far more efficient overall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want to put it in a setinterval.

```
//this is assuming that heroHealth, and healthDisplay 
//are available to this function already 
//either through closure or they are global 
//variables etc.

function checkHealth () {

if (heroHealth > 75) {
        healthDisplay.src = 'image1.png';
      } else if (heroHealth < 75 && heroHealth > 30){
        healthDisplay.src = 'image2.png';
      } else {
        healthDisplay.src = 'image3.png';
      };
}

setInterval(checkHealth, 100);
```

The [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) calls a function repeatedly at certain intervals.  This example is set to 100 milliseconds.  This way as the hero's health goes up and down, the image src will change as the function fires.

Depending on how your game is set up and how the health is stored, you could wire up the function to an on change event:

```
<input type="textbox" id="heroHealthCheckBox" 
  onchange="checkHeroHealth(this.value)"/>

function checkHeroHealth(health) {
  var heroHealth = parseInt(health);
  if (heroHealth > 75) {
    healthDisplay.src = 'image1.png';
  } else if (heroHealth < 75 && heroHealth > 30){
    healthDisplay.src = 'image2.png';
  } else {
    healthDisplay.src = 'image3.png';
  }
}
```

I also changed the second conditional from

```
heroHealth < 75 || heroHealth > 30
```

to this

```
heroHealth < 75 && heroHealth > 30
```

Comment: What if clicking somewhere changes the health rate instead of time?

Comment: Well I would assume that clicking on something would raise or lower the health, and when the function fires, it will note the change and update the image.

Comment: But in that case, calling the function 10 times in a second would be in vain and it may effect the speed of the game on browsers.

Comment: Yes, but you can change the interval, mine was just an example of 100 milliseconds there is nothing to say that it can't be just once a second.  Browsers are pretty efficient too, they've come along way since they were first introduced.  I would guess that the amount of work on a setinterval call is going to be negligible.

Comment: It's a pretty straightforward and basic game, and the health is stored as a global variable that is '-= 1' each time they collide with an object.  The setinterval worked great for the first image change but it didn't trigger to render the final (image3) image.  Is there a problem with the if/else statement itself?

Comment: I missed that. Change this: heroHealth < 75 || heroHealth > 30 to this heroHealth < 75 && heroHealth > 30